# Parsing JSON from wikiarticle. Strange json result

Tags: json, wikipedia-api

I like to parse all sections of a wikiarticle. This works fine for most pages, but I have problems with a specific one, which I can't explain why it is not working:

Calling restpoint 1 works fine and I get the section structured as JSON:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text={{:Galileo_Galilei}}&prop=sections&format=json
```

Calling the same in another language doesn't return any section, but they exist:

```
https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text={{:Galileo_Galilei}}&prop=sections&format=json
```

returns only :

```
{"warnings":{"parse":{"*":"No \"title\" or \"contentmodel\" was gi

ven, assuming wikitext."}},"parse":{"title":"API","pageid":180443,"sections":[]}}
```

Does anyone have an explanation or a hint how can I parse the sections for the german wikiarticle Galileo Galilei ?

Comment: What text is inside the variable `{{:Galileo_Galilei}}`?  please mention the entire route with the parameters without using the variable...

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved it. Not sure, but correct URL would be for the solution :

```
https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Galileo_Galilei&prop=sections&format=json
```

I don't know where I got the old wrong link.